# Accessing Skype API from desktop app

Tags: skypedeveloper

I have been using the Skype4COM.dll to let my app access Skype.
At some point of time this didn't work anymore, and I learnt that Skype / Microsoft disabled this functionality.

I put so much into making this work, and then suddenly this function was disabled without any clear forewarning, leaving it to me to explain to customers why something in my app doesn't work anymore which obviously should do work.

I would like to ask if there is a new way to access Skype via a desktop app again.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Have you found the answer? I had project where I used skype4com also. Planning to update it now.